# Combining CSV files with Python without repeat elements

Tags: python, csv, glob

I'm trying to write a python (2.7) script to add multiple CSV lists together (simple append), but not add any lines from file X that share an element (other than in first column) with file Y.  Here's my trial script:

```
import csv
import glob

with open('merged.csv','wb') as out:
    seen = set()
    output = []
    out_writer = csv.writer(out)
    csv_files = glob.glob('*.csv')
    for filename in csv_files:
        with open(filename, 'rb') as ifile:
            read = csv.reader(ifile)
            for row in read:
                if {row[1] not in seen} & {row[2] not in seen} & {row[3] not in seen}:
                    seen.add(row[1])
                    seen.add(row[2])
                    seen.add(row[3])
                    output.append(row)
    out_writer.writerows(output)
```

I'm sure this can be cleaned up some, but it's the trial run - why isn't it properly adding elements from columns 2, 3, and 4 to the seen set and then not appending the row if they appear in the considered row?  Other than checking properly for repeats, it's successfully outputting a merged file.  (Will this also work if the merged file already exists in the directory, or will I get into trouble with that?)

Thanks so much in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this line does not do what you want:

```
if {row[1] not in seen} & {row[2] not in seen} & {row[3] not in seen}:
```

That's a set intersection. Demo:

```
>>> {False} & {True}
set([])
>>> {True} & {True}
set([True])
>>> {False} & {False}
set([False])
>>> bool(set([False]))
True    #non-empty set is True in boolean context
```

Maybe you intended

```
if row[1] not in seen and row[2] not in seen and row[3] not in seen:
```

or (almost*) equivalent

```
if all(value not in seen for value in row[1:4]):
```

(*) this does not raise an exception if there are fewer values in the row